# Probability rule involving conditional and marginal distributions

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

The context of my question is Baysian generative models. The text book I am reading states

$p(\tilde{x} \, \vert \, D) = \int p(\tilde{x} \, \vert \, \theta) p(\theta \, \vert \, D) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$.

where $p(\tilde{x} \vert D)$ is the posterior predictive distribution ($\tilde{x}$ is a new data point, $D$ is the training data), and $p(\theta \vert D)$ is the posterior distribution ($\theta$ is the parameter of the model, $D$ as before is the training data).

This equation seems intuitively true, but I am having trouble proving it mathematically using the basic rules of conditional, marginal, etc. distributions.

Moreover, I think the general statement is not true. By which I mean, I think with random variables $X, Y, Z$, it is not the case that

$p(X \vert Z) = \int p(X \vert Y) p(Y \vert Z) \, \mathrm{d}Y$

What, then, is the relationship that must hold between $X, Y, Z$ such that the above statement is true? Is it that we must have $p(Y \vert Z) = p(Y)$?

In addition, if anyone can show me a proof of the first statement, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider adding a "self-study"  tag to your question.

Comment: @Kostia Added! (Sorry, was not aware of this convention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the work below:
\begin{eqnarray}
p(\tilde{x}|D) &=& \int{p(\tilde{x},\theta|D)d\theta}\\
&=& \int{p(\tilde{x}|\theta,D)p(\theta|D)d\theta}\\
&=& \int{p(\tilde{x}|\theta)p(\theta|D)d\theta}
\end{eqnarray}
Note that between lines 2 and 3, we equate $p(\tilde{x}|\theta,D)$ with $p(\tilde{x}|\theta)$. This relies on the assumption that your new training point $\tilde{x}$ is independent of your training data $D$. This makes theoretical sense - if your new training point is dependent on your training data, then you may run into issues when generalizing beyond your training data. However, it is important to make sure that this is a realistic assumption under whatever practical conditions you have when gathering your data.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about $\tilde{x}$ being independent from $D$, but then I think about it and get confused again, because doesn't $D$ determine $\theta$, which affect $\tilde{x}$? Would it be more correct it say that $\tilde{x}$ is conditionally independent from $D$ conditioned on $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, $\tilde{x}|\theta$ is independent of $D$. I think of it from the perspective that the distribution of $\tilde{x}|\theta$ and $\tilde{x}|\theta,D$ will be the same because, conditional upon $\theta$, $D$ provides no new information about $\tilde{x}$. More colloquially, you might say that $D$ affects $\theta$ which in turn affects $\tilde{x}$, but if you take $\theta$ into account, then $D$ has no additional effect on $\tilde{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I think with random variables $X,Y,Z$ it is not the case that 
>   $$
> p(X|Z)=\int p(X|Y)p(Y|Z)dY
> $$

You are absolutely correct. The easiest way to see that the above equation does not generally hold is to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The right-hand-side then reduces to $p(X)$.

To fix that equation, [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) the definition of the marginal PDF:

$$
p(X)=\int p(X|Y)p(Y)dY
$$

In your case, you have $p(X|Z)$ instead of $p(X)$ and you are now one step from the correct formula.

Comment: Yup, this makes sense, so I think the correct formula should be $p(X \vert Z) = \int p(X \vert Y, Z) p(Y \vert Z) \, \mathrm{d}Y$.

Comment: @anon_student   That is right.